# $R$ commutative ring with unity. Prove if $R/M$ is a field $\implies M$ is a max ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, maximal-and-prime-ideals

$R$ commutative ring with unity. Prove if $R/M$ is a field $\implies M$ is a max ideal.

Let us propose the opposite: that M isn't the max ideal. So $$I \triangleleft R, M\nsubseteq I$$ (How this is opposite of  M not being the max ideal i don't understand). Now we take $a\in R$ and $b \in I|M$ $; R|M$ field $\implies \exists  x+M; a+M=(x+M)(b+M)$
$$a+M=bx+M$$
$$a+M-(bx-M)=M \implies a-bx \in M;$$ $$ **a - bx \in I;b\in I \implies a\in I \implies I=R**$$

I don't understand the highlighted and the brackets before.. Can anyone help ?

Comment: What does $I\Delta R$ mean?

Comment: I is an ideal in R

Comment: You mean $I\triangleleft R$. Use \triangleleft.

Comment: For your first question, we are assuming that $M$ and $I$ are two ideal ideals and that $M \subsetneq I \subsetneq R$.

Comment: $**a-bx \in I;b\in I \implies a\in I **$ because $a-bx+bx =a \in I$, note that $b \in I \implies bx \in I$

Comment: How do we know that $a-bx \in I$ i don;t understand

Comment: Can't $a-bx \notin I$ because $M \subsetneq I \subsetneq R$

Comment: @Bhaskar Vashishth take a look at these questions i layed out, i think you can help..

Comment: You showed that $a-bx \in M \subset I$. So what is the problem here?

Comment: Pardon, I forgot the meaning of  $\subsetneq $ for a second.

Comment: You chose a to be any element of R, and you showed it lies in R, therefore you,  I is contained in R,  hence equal

Comment: How is$\ \  b \in I $ after $; b \in I|M , a \in R ; a−bx \in I $? Just this part I do not understand.. :)